# Image processing related discussion forum

Tags: image-processing, forums

I am looking for discussion forum for Image processing related queries,
Can someone direct me some discussion groups,

Though I am a beginner, I am catching up fast ;-) ...

Comment: Well, you can follow this - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86832. All needed is to up vote questions with less than 10 points. Once enough people will do it, will have a community dedicated to Image Processing,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think such questions fit well on Stack Overflow.  Try us! :)

Comment: Thanks, just worried about the down-votes for non-programming questions ... ;-)))

Comment: There are quite a few image-processing questions, just check out the tag.